# A courier has to make 5 stops on his route, designated $A, B, C, D$, and $E$. Count Distinct routes with A sometime before D

Tags: combinatorics

> A courier has to make 5 stops on his route, designated $A, B, C, D$, and $E$. How many distinct routes can he take if he must stop at $A$ sometime before $D$ ?

Suppose that "AD" is an independent letter.

B,C,E has 6 arrangements.

Now we may insert "AD" before the first letter of all arrangement of BCE, before the second letter of all arrangements of BCE, or after the last letter of all arrangements of BCE.

I think the answer is $24=3! \cdot 4$ but the answer key says 60.

Comment: The question says "$A$ sometime before $D$", not $A$ immediately before $D$.

Comment: For example, $ABCDE$ is a valid sequence of stops, but your approach didn't count this.

Comment: How many arrangements of the five stops are there in all? Of those, what fraction have $A$ before $D$, and what fraction have $D$ before $A$?

Comment: Symmetry: A before D is as likely as D before A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

B,C,E has $3!$ arrangements.

A,D arrangements are ten

```
(1,2),(1,3)(1,4),(1,5)
(2,3),(2,4),(2,5)
(3,4),(3,5)
(4,5)
```

60 is the answer

Comment: There are five ways to place $B$, four ways to place $C$, and three ways to place $D$.  There is only one way to place $A$ and $D$ in the remaining two positions so that $A$ appears before $D$.  Hence, there are $5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 = 60$ admissible arrangements.

Answer (score 2):

As the comments have already indicated, symmetrical considerations require that the answer is

$$\frac{5!}{2} = 60.$$

However, your direct approach is also feasible.

There are $~\displaystyle \binom{5}{2}~$ ways of selecting the two positions that will be occupied by A and D.  Once these two positions are selected, since A must precede D, the positions of A and D are therefore set.

Then, there are $(3)$ positions left, to be occupied by the stops B,C,E, in any order.  These $(3)$ stops can be permuted in $(3!)$ ways.

Therefore, the alternative computation is

$$\binom{5}{2} \times (3!) = 60.$$

Comment: How does 5 choose 2 account for the A before D? @user2661923 It's a combination and not a permutation. in combinations order doesn't matter.

Comment: @BoredStar It doesn't.  $~\displaystyle \binom{5}{2}~$ accounts for selecting the two positions that will be occupied by A and D, in *some* order.  **If** A was (also) permitted to come **after** D, then you would have to apply the *permutation factor* of $(2!)$.  Since the constraint outlaws A coming after D, no *permutation factor* is required.

Comment: @BoredStar: Another way to think about it is that that's exactly *why* it accounts for A before D. If we leave spots $2$ and $5$ for A and D in BXECX (for example), then we only want to count the combination once, not the permutation twice, because we know that those spots only yield one sequence (BAECD) and not two (BAECD and the illegal BDECA).